# How to select ":even" parents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to make an if-statement where if the button's parent is an even child of it's parent, do `alert("it works");`, else do `alert("nope");`, it's probably something really easy, I'm really new to this! :) Here's my current code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button>#0</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>#1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>#2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>#3</button>
    </div>
</div>​
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            var $parent = $(this).parent();
            if ($parent.is(":even")) {
                alert("it works");
            } else {
                alert("nope");
            }
        });
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/goldson/Rn6gz/1/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index and use modulos operator `%` to know if it is `event` or `odd`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn6gz/3/)**

```
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if ($parent.index() % 2 == 0) {
            alert("it works");
        } else {
            alert("nope");
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I was thinking of using index() to begin with, will probably go with it. Why won't ":even" work though?

Answer (score 3):

One work around is to add classes to your even div elements:

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ujivem/1/)**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div>
        <button>#0</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>#1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>#2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>#3</button>
    </div>
</div>


$(function () {

    var arr = $('#parentDiv div');
    arr.filter(":even").addClass("even");

    $("button").click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if ($parent.is(".even")) {
            alert("it works");
        } else {
            alert("nope");
        }
    });
```

});